# Equivalence relation on set $X$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science

Me and my friends were complaining about one of the exercises in discrete math.

If there are two equivalence relations $R_1$ and $R_2$ on set $X$.
Is $R_{1}\setminus R_{2}$ still an equivalence relation?

My example:

If set $X = \{a,b,c\}$

$$\begin{align}
R_{1} &= \{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(a,b),(b,a)\}\\
R_{2} &= \{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(a,c),(c,a)\}
\end{align}$$

$R_{1}\setminus R_{2} = \{(a,b),(b,a)\}$ which isn't an equivalence relation.

Some of them say that $R_{1}\setminus R_{2}$ is still an equivalence relation (not necessarily on my example)

Can someone make it clear for me and rest of us?

Comment: You have provided a counterexample, which shows the statement is false. For the same reason your counterexample works, $R_1\setminus R_2$ can never be an equivalence relation: since $(x,x) \in R_1$ and $(x,x) \in R_2$ for all $x \in X$, $(x,x) \notin R_1 \setminus R_2$ for any $x \in X$. (I suppose the only case in which $R_1\setminus R_2$ _is_ still an equivalence relation is the trivial case where $X$ is the empty set.)

Comment: No, because it doesn't, can't, contain the diagonal of $X$, $\{(x,x)\mid x\in X\}$. That is, $R_1\setminus R_2$ is not reflexive. As your example illustrates, the difference **is** always symmetric. But it won't be transitive either, unless it's empty, because it doesn't contain the diagonal: if $(a,b)$ is in the difference, then so is $(b,a)$, so if it were transitive then $(a,a)$ would be in the difference, but it isn't.